# ASP.net Using a Session Varriable to move a GridView SelectedDataKey to another page

Tags: asp.net

Help please!

I am pulling out what little hair I have left over this and can't find an answer.

I am attempting to move the selected row in a grid view to another page and use the SelectedDataKey or the primary key value of the selected row to indicate what data should be displayed in a grid view on another page.  This is the last little bit of a school project that I can't figure out.

What I am doing on the first page is to use a button click event to set a session variable that looks something like this.  Session["Select"] = GridView1.SelectedDataKey; The button will then send the user to the next page. Response.Redirect("CustomerAccounts.aspx");

Once on the next page I want to use the primary key selected on the first page to show only the data with a coresponding value on the second page by using a where statement in the next gridview.  So I am setting the [CustomerID]=? Session("Session["Select"])

Am I setting up the where correctly in the second gridview?

Comment: Session variable is not the preferred method to pass those sort of values, would be better to pass it as a query parameter.

Comment: I am required to use a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I like setting up such things with querystrings.
I made a video tutorial on youtube doing just that a while back
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRjZ_0JpO2M&list=UUgtKyNvllU9E6c2Mi8OtzCQ&index=5&feature=plcp

I also made a tutorial showing how to load the detail gridview nested in the master gridview with jquery
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJp14o_1wZQ&list=UUgtKyNvllU9E6c2Mi8OtzCQ&index=4&feature=plcp